# Highlighted cells that use formulas won't copy the highlight to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that highlights cells in a column that uses formulas.
I'm using this code to highlight the cells:

```
With Sheets("Sheets1").Range("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End With
```

However, I'm trying to use another script to copy this data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 and when I run the script, the highlighting is removed from the cell but the data is still copied into the new sheet (Sheet 2).`

```
Sheets("Sheets2").Range("G3:G100").Copy
Sheets("Sheets2").Activate
Sheets("Sheets2").Range("A1").Offset(0, l - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`
```

I need assistance trying to copy the cells over to the other sheet and to maintain the highlight on the cells that use a formula.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are pasting values the formats don't come along.  Add a second paste as follows:

```
Sheets("Sheets2").Range("A1").Offset(0, l - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```